# Magento 2 - catch NoSuchEntityException

Tags: magento2, exception

I have following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($order->getCustomerId());
$mitgliedsnummer = $customer->getCustomAttribute('mitgliedsnummer');
```

When a customer has been deleted and this code gets executed it throws

> NoSuchEntityException

However I want the code to continue. 
What can I do?

Thanks!

Update:

After applying simonthesorcerers suggestion it still happens.

```
    try {
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($order->getCustomerId());
    } catch(NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        $customer = null;
    }
    error_log("Test");
```

Update 2:
include

> use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
>   to your namespace.

Thanks to simonthesorcerer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the question, you should simply use a `try...catch` construct. This is an example:

```
try {
    $mitgliedsnummer = $customer->getCustomAttribute('mitgliedsnummer');
} catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    // do something with $e, for example log $e->getMessage()
}
// code will continue to run here
```

More can be found in the official docs: http://php.net/manual/de/language.exceptions.php

However, remember that `$mitgliedsnummer` will have no value afterwards, so your program should be able to deal with that and may simple `return $this;` in the `catch() {}` segment.

You should also use dependency injection in your class's `__construct()` method instead of the `ObjectManager`, see the official docs here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html

Comment: It still prints an error site then

Comment: is it the same error? do you have `use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;` after your `namespace`declaration? ; edited my answer and added full path

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($order->getCustomerId());
    } catch(Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        continue;        
}
```